# ${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']} is coming as empty

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

With `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}`< I am able to get proper value from my URL..say for e.g

If I have URL `http://localhost:8080/myapp/request1`, I am able to get `/myapp/request1` with the help of `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path']}`, however there will be cases where URL might have some query-string appended to it like `http://localhost:8080/myapp/request1?text=abc`

In this case I want URL including query String `/myapp/request1?text=abc`, I tried to use `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}` but this is coming as empty.

Can anyone help me to understand as where `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.query_string']}` ca be empty? or what is best way to handle above mentioned 2 cases

Answer (score 1):

To get the context relative path with query Strings appended, use this code from a filter or a front controller servlet:

```
contextRelativePath = request.getRequestURI().substring(
                request.getContextPath().length()).toLowerCase().trim();
String queryString = request.getQueryString();
if(queryString != null){
    contextRelativePath += queryString;
}
request.setAttribute("path", contextRelativePath);
```

You can now access the path from your JSP as in ${path}